# How to ensure Spark Streaming is reading new records only from selected partition in source?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a PySpark Streaming pipeline in Databricks which is reading from a partitioned source table, with a filter on the field the source table is partitioned on. This streaming pipeline is using the trigger "availableNow", which ideally should process all the new records since the last run in microbatches, and it is identifying the new records using Spark Streaming Checkpoint.

The source table primarily has 2 partitions, one of which is updated in realtime, the second is updated thrice a day, just before my Spark Streaming Pipeline is triggered. MY streaming pipeline has a filter to read only from the second partition

My problem is that my streaming pipeline, where the trigger is set to availableNow, is running endlessly and not loading any records. This is the statistics from the last batch

```
{
  "id" : "2977e694-ed62-4859-b936-c9086274882d",
  "runId" : "5eb801aa-ba7a-4475-983b-8fde13213684",
  "name" : null,
  "timestamp" : "2023-11-28T08:51:36.080Z",
  "batchId" : 54,
  "numInputRows" : 0,
  "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 101872,
    "commitOffsets" : 71,
    "getBatch" : 140,
    "latestOffset" : 166,
    "queryPlanning" : 69,
    "triggerExecution" : 102517,
    "walCommit" : 193
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "DeltaSource[s3://*********/******/****/***]",
    "startOffset" : {
      "sourceVersion" : 1,
      "reservoirId" : "287e19cb-c1cf-4410-b514-b8f7c4683cfd",
      "reservoirVersion" : 53967,
      "index" : 47,
      "isStartingVersion" : false
    },
    "endOffset" : {
      "sourceVersion" : 1,
      "reservoirId" : "287e19cb-c1cf-4410-b514-b8f7c4683cfd",
      "reservoirVersion" : 53967,
      "index" : 64,
      "isStartingVersion" : false
    },
    "latestOffset" : null,
    "numInputRows" : 0,
    "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
    "metrics" : {
      "numBytesOutstanding" : "4878832268134",
      "numFilesOutstanding" : "62526"
    }
  } ],
  "sink" : {
    "description" : "ForeachBatchSink",
    "numOutputRows" : -1
  }
}
```

As shown above, the `numInputRows` is zero but `numFilesOutstanding` is non-zero, which implies it is trying to reading files which are not part of this stream. And also, if I stop this stream, and not update this source partition at all, and restart the stream, the `numFilesOutstanding` increases, which gives me the idea that the source partition which is being updated in realtime is adding files to be read. It is trying to read those files, not getting any for this partition, and is moving on

I have provided the code below where I am reading the data and then merging the data into the table after performing some transformations

```
(
    spark.readStream.format("delta")
    .option("ignoreChanges", "true")
    .option("maxBytesPerTrigger", self.bytes_to_process)
    .option("maxFilesPerTrigger", self.files_to_process)
    .table(self.silver_table)
    .filter(col("RECORD_SOURCE") == "SOURCE_2")
    .filter(f"CONCAT(ORDER_YEAR, ORDER_MONTH) >= '202306'")
    .writeStream.format("delta")
    .foreachBatch(self.process_streaming_batch)
    .option("checkpointLocation", self.checkpoint)
    .trigger(availableNow=True).start()
)
```

The source table is partitioned on RECORD_SOURCE, ORDER_YEAR and ORDER_MONTH, the record source SOURCE_1 is updated in realtime and SOURCE_2 is updated thrice a day

My question is mainly 2 part

1. Is this a use case that someone has encountered before and is this behavior expected?
2. Is there any way I can restrict the streaming application to read only from the partition required

I tried deleting the checkpoint and restarting the job. The first run completes as expected, then from the next run I am encountering the same problem.

I am using the option "ignoreChanges" as "true" in my job, since the source is also running the UPDATE operation in addition to INSERT. I read that as of DBR12.2, it is deprecated in favor of "skipChangeCommits", I tried changing the option to that and it is still the same.

Splitting the source table into 2 tables based on the partitions is my last option, but I want to explore other options before that.

Comment: Show your code - how you read & write the data

Comment: @AlexOtt I have updated the question with the read code. The final dataset is being merged into the gold table, which is partitioned on another set of columns, but I do not think the issue is there, since there are 0 input rows to begin with